# One vertex buffer with varying width

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I would like to draw lines from one vertex buffer with changing width. Is it possible or i can change width only using `glLineWidth`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is using a geometry shader. See here

https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/smooth-thick-lines-using-geometry-shader

And these

https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/179732-Line-thickness

http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/156650-Is-it-possible-to-change-line-width-somehow-besides-glLineWidth()